# Shouldn't question like "why is x nicknamed y", "why is x called y" be closed as primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was wondering what happens in this type of question aren't they considered as opinion based. If they are not could I ask question like this because I could ask so many different question like this.

Question I have found which are not closed:

[Why is Matt Ryan nicknamed “Matty Ice”?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15359/why-is-matt-ryan-nicknamed-matty-ice)

[Why is Darren Lehmann called 'Boof'](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2822/why-is-darren-lehmann-called-boof)

I would like if someone told me the reason they are not opinion based?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this as being "opinion based" - in most cases, there's going to be a good reason why a certain player has a certain nickname. Looking (e.g.) at the Matt Ryan one, there's a good answer which gives a direct quote from a reputable source; that's the exact opposite of "opinion based", as it's nothing to do with the poster's personal opinion.

Comment: Sir thanks for clarifying this, what happens when different reputable sources have different views.